# implement the dictionary entry

Tags: python, python-3.x

please help to fix the script. it should provide an opportunity to introduce a new element of the dictionary.

```
keys = ['id', 'type', 'number'];

rec1 = {'id': 1, 'type': 'c', 'number': 111}
rec2 = {'id': 2, 'type': 'c', 'number': 222}
rec3 = {'id': 3, 'type': 'c', 'number': 333}

db = {}

db['c111'] = rec1
db['c222'] = rec2
db['c333'] = rec3

def outputDB():
    for record in db:
        print(record, ': ', db[record])
        for item in db[record]:    
            print(item, '--', db[record][item])
        print('-----')

action = int(input('1 - print, 2 - write'))

if(action == 1):
    outputDB()
else:
    indexKey = str(input('enter indexKey: '))
    db.a
    for key in keys:
        print('enter value for ', key)
        value = str(input('enter value: '))
        db[indexKey][key] = value
    outputDB()
```

but in the last cycle, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:\Python33\projects\p3_dvd_list\index.py", line 35, in <module>
    db[indexKey][key] = value KeyError: 'qqq'
```

Comment: What is the input you are using to test it?

Comment: What's with the `db.a` before `for key in keys:`. `dict` object has no attribute `a`, does it?

Comment: sorry. this is my another bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign a `dict` to `db[indexKey]` before assigning a value to a key of `db[indexKey]`:

This:

```
db[indexKey] = dict()
db[indexKey][key] = value
```

not this:

```
db[indexKey][key] = value  # won't work; assumes db[indexKey] is already a dict, but you haven't assigned a value to it
```

Comment: It can be written in one line:

    db.setdefault(indexKey, {})[key] = value